# FastAPI server is not accessible from local network

Tags: backend, fastapi, firewall, blocking, local-network

I have the backend done on `FastAPI` and the frontend made on ReactJS. Both of them run on a local PC, using different ports (`back - 192.168.X.X:8000, front - 192.168.X.X:3000`).

I can access React app from other PCs (`in the same network`), and also can send curl requests from my PC. Everything is great. **However, the same doesn't work for the backend**.
I neither can access the `192.168.X.X:8000/docs` API from any other PC in the local network, nor I can send curl requests to that URL. Also, I tried to access it from my PC in the browser and it throws "took too long to respond". There is no error in the `FastAPI` logs. I created a rule for `port 8000 in the firewall`, and also tried to switch it off for the private network. In `CORS` origins for `FastAPI`, I tried to allow everything using wildcard **["*"]**, and also I tried to allow specific IPs manually. Both of those methods didn't help. Does anyone have an idea what could be the cause of the problem?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @Chris, I have read the answer by that link. Unfortunately, the methods described there  do not resolve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, silly me. It was just background apps blocking incoming connection. If anybody faces this problem, make sure that any safe-transaction, internet traffic control apps are off.